# parsing html input element in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

There is a website I am trying to parse: https://www.cryptomkt.com/es/chile 
I am trying to obtain the value of ethereum, which I think in the source code is represented by this line:

```
<input type="text" class="input-center" id="valor_eth" name="valor_eth" disabled="">
```

But I can't do it with beautiful soup, since the number is not hardcoded. I am a noob regarding web developing and programming crawlers, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price is dynamic loaded from a json file. That you can inspect it from web browser's developer tools.

So what you want to do is to parse that json file, and get the latest price.

```
import urllib.request
import json
sourcefile = 'https://www.cryptomkt.com/api/ethclp/1440.json'
prices = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(sourcefile).read().decode('utf-8'))
low_price = prices['data']['prices_ask']['values'][0]['low_price']
print(low_price)
```

Comment: thank you very much, this one worked. One last question, how did you get to the api/ethclp/1440.json site? it doesn't appear on the source of the first page.

Comment: Actually  I am checking that the json file you send it's not the one that the site is fetching from. The json shows daily information, and the site I put here changes every 15 seconds.

Comment: Press `F12`, and go to the `Network` panel, then reload the page. You can see the `1440.json` file, or you can filter it through the XHR button.  See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filters